# Test DelegateCommand async without needing to make handler public

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Using the **DelegateCommand** within **Prism** it is no longer possible to await the command execution since FromAsyncHanlder was removed from version **6.3**.

For unit testing the recommendation is to port as below, so if you have

```
Task MyHandler() {...}
DelegateCommand myCommand = DelegateCommand.FromAsyncHandler(MyHandler);
/// in test:
await myCommand.Execute();
```

change it to

```
DelegateCommand myCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await MyHandler());
/// in test:
await MyHandler();
```

This however requires the command handler (MyHandler) to be made public which negates the encapsulation benefits of using the command pattern.

I know that I can use/create other command implementations but I like DelegateCommand as it is part of Prism and regularly maintained.

Is there a better way of testing async commands using the DelegateCommand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way of testing async commands using the DelegateCommand?

Not really. Since the `DelegateCommand` class doesn't expose any async and awaitable methods, you cannot await the command itself I am afraid.

You could make the `MyHandler()` method `internal` and apply the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to your assembly:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("UnitTests")]
```

Maybe that's a bit better. Your other options are basically to make the method `public` or use another `ICommand` implementation that supports `async`/`await`.

Comment: That's heading in the right direction, having the handler as internal at least indicates my intent.

Answer (score 0):

What would you say about following approach:

```
public class AsyncDelegateCommand : DelegateCommand
{
    private Func<Task> executeAction;

    public AsyncDelegateCommand(Func<Task> executeAction) : base(async () => { await executeAction(); })
    {
        this.executeAction =  executeAction;
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        if (CanExecute())
        {
            try
            {
                IsActive = true;
                await executeAction();
            }
            finally
            {
                IsActive = false;
            }
        }

        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

And it can be tested just like:

```
await myCommand.ExecuteAsync();
```